# Why does PostGIS ST_IsSolid return false for a closed object with a volume

Tags: postgis, sfcgal

POSTGIS=3.3.4, SFCGAL=SFCGAL 1.4.1

Unexpected: IsSolid of MakeSolid returns false (I'd expect it to return true)

[image: IsSolid of MakeSolid returning false]

But my 3D object returns true for IsClosed

[image: isClosed returns true]

And it also has a measurable volume:

[image]

Why is ST_IsSolid returning false? Is there something else wrong with my object?

```
POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z:

SELECT ST_IsSolid (ST_MakeSolid(ST_GeomFromText('POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((1 -0.416666656732559 0, -1 -0.416666656732559 0, -1 0.416666656732559 0, 1 -0.416666656732559 0)),((-1 0.416666656732559 0, 1 0.416666656732559 0, 1 -0.416666656732559 0, -1 0.416666656732559 0)),((1 -0.416666656732559 12, 1 -0.416666656732559 0, 1 0.416666656732559 0, 1 -0.416666656732559 12)),((1 0.416666656732559 0, 1 0.416666656732559 12, 1 -0.416666656732559 12, 1 0.416666656732559 0)),((-1 -0.416666656732559 12, -1 -0.416666656732559 0, 1 -0.416666656732559 0, -1 -0.416666656732559 12)),((1 -0.416666656732559 0, 1 -0.416666656732559 12, -1 -0.416666656732559 12, 1 -0.416666656732559 0)),((-1 0.416666656732559 12, -1 0.416666656732559 0, -1 -0.416666656732559 0, -1 0.416666656732559 12)),((-1 -0.416666656732559 0, -1 -0.416666656732559 12, -1 0.416666656732559 12, -1 -0.416666656732559 0)),((1 0.416666656732559 12, 1 0.416666656732559 0, -1 0.416666656732559 0, 1 0.416666656732559 12)),((-1 0.416666656732559 0, -1 0.416666656732559 12, 1 0.416666656732559 12, -1 0.416666656732559 0)),((-1 0.416666656732559 12, -1 -0.416666656732559 12, 1 -0.416666656732559 12, -1 0.416666656732559 12)),((1 -0.416666656732559 12, 1 0.416666656732559 12, -1 0.416666656732559 12, 1 -0.416666656732559 12)) )')));
```